# JUNG force directed graph

Tags: java, jung, jung2

I am trying to build a force directed graph in JUNG, similar to the ones you can create (very easily) in D3.js.

Most of it is very simple but the docs are a bit old and the examples dont include a force directed one (although there is a java applet on there that claims to be a demo but it shows nothing)

Anyway, using a `DirectedSparseGraph` I have achieve most of the functionality:

```
directedGraph = new DirectedSparseGraph();

directedGraph.addVertex("someVertex");
directedGraph.addVertex("someOtherVertex");
// etc
directedGraph.addEdge("someVertex", "someOtherVertex");
// etc
```

This gives me almost exactly what I want but I can't figure out how to assign a length to the edges to show differing forces. I've looked through the docs and Google but can't find anything.

I'd expect something like
`directedGraph.addEdge([edge 1], [edge 2], [edge length]);` but it doesn't seem to exist in the api.

Anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

N.b. jung version is 2.0.1

Comment: Some related [tag:prefuse] examples are examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bprefuse%5d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking at jung-1.x docs. In jung-2.x [`DirectedSparseGraph<V, E>`](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/DirectedSparseGraph.html) is a generic class with type parameters for vertices `V` and edges `E`.

This is also the method to define vertices and edges with arbitrary properties. E.g. if you want to have edge weights, create a suitable edge class with a weight:

```
class Edge {
    public double weight;
}
```

Note that you usually also want to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` at least for vertices.

If you want to use the weight for layouting (e.g. in [`SpringLayout`](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/layout/SpringLayout.html), [one of the constructors](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/layout/SpringLayout.html#SpringLayout%28edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph,%20org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer%29)  takes a `lengthFunction`.